# ¿Cómo contar el número total de funciones en Python?

Tags: python

Tengo un código con muchas funciones `def()`, querría saber si existe alguna forma de *contar* el número de funciones que hay dentro de una **clase**

```
class Main:
    def a(self):
        print("A")

    def b(self):
        print("B")

    def c(self):
        print("C")
    . . .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar `inspect`:

- Sobre una referencia a la clase:

  ```
  import inspect
  print(len(inspect.getmembers(Main, predicate=inspect.isfunction)))
  ```
- Sobre una referencia a un objeto de la clase (`bound method`):

  ```
  import inspect
  print(len(inspect.getmembers(Main(), predicate=inspect.ismethod)))
  ```

Ten en cuenta que:

- Los métodos de instancia heredados de otras clases (si la clase hereda de algo más que de `object`) también son listados.
- Los métodos mágicos (`__init__`, `__str__`, etc) también se incluyen siempre que sean definidos o sobrescritos en la clase o alguna de las clases padre. En caso contrario, (method-wrapper (`__repr__`, `__setattr__`, etc) / buit-in method (`__new__`, `__init__subclass__`, etc)) no son incluidos.
- Las properties propias o heredadas (aunque son callables) no son listadas.
- Los métodos de clase propios o heredados no son listados en el primer caso, si en el segundo. Si quieres incluirlos puedes hacer:

  ```
  import inspect

  print(len(inspect.getmembers(
      Main, predicate=lambda m: inspect.isfunction(m) or inspect.ismethod(m))
      ))
  ```
- Los métodos estáticos propios o heredados se incluyen en el primer caso pero no en el segundo.

Como puede verse, no es tan simple como parece, no se que utilidad quieres darle a esto exactamente, pero dada la naturaleza dinámica de Python y que casi todo se puede modificar incluso pasándo toda convención y sentido común por la guillotina debes tener cuidado si lo aplicas a clases que no controles tu mismo especialmente.

Comment: Esto incluye a la función __init__ de la clase?

Comment: Por supuesto, el inicializador no tiene nada de especial en este caso. ¿Quieres que ningún método mágico sea listado (`__init__, __new__, __str__, __repr__, __contains__`, etc)? ¿Los métodos "privados" `def _metodo(self)` y los que usa name mangling `def __metodo(self)` deberían listarse o tampoco?

Comment: Segun comprobé usando el __primer__ ejemplo que proporcionaste, el resultado son 122 clases, y en mi código, si contamos la clase *init*, son 123

Comment: Se cuenta seguro, puedes añadirle un `__init__` a tu ejemplo de tres métodos y comprobarlo. Como comento las propiedades no se cuentan por ejemplo. Los métodos de clase tampoco lo hacen si usas una referencia a la clase, si se cuentan si usas referencia a un objeto de la misma. ¿Seguro que todo lo que tienes son métodos de instancia como muestras en el ejemplo?

Comment: Ahora es funcional, gracias. Al probarlo con el ejmplo que usé si que funciona, pero al implementarlo en mi código no contaba el __init__